# Items in combobox reduced after adding actionPerformed

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, combobox

I want to update my table right after clicking on a diffrent item in combobox. After adding actionPerformed combobox shows only the first item and the arrow doesn't work. I'm updating my table after selecting a diffrent item and clicking a button. Action perform in a button does work. Am I using the actionPerformed incorrectly?

Here is a code how I add items to a combobox.

```
private void fillComboBox() {       
    try {
        DatabaseMetaData meta = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
        rs = meta.getTables("db", null, null, new String[] {
          "TABLE"
        });
        while (rs.next()) {
            ComboBox.addItem(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
        }            
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);         
    }
}
```

Here is how I fill the table.

```
private void fillTable()
{
    String selectedValue = ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sql = "Select * from "+selectedValue;
    Statement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,rs.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        Table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}
```

And after clicking a button, I update the table

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    fillTable();
}
```

Works fine, but I would like to update the table right after clicking on a new item in combobox.

Edit: I fixed it by adding fillComboBox() after fillTable(). But now I have two first items in combobox even after removeAll(). How do I fix it?

```
public Welcome() {
    initComponents();
    conn = MySqlConnect.ConnectDB();
    fillComboBox();
    fillTable();
    ComboBox.removeAll();
    fillComboBox();
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always change contents of a ComboBox dynamically by using the underlying Model, not through the actual ComboBox. After your GUI is already shown, I think this matters ... using the model, not the JComboBox itself.

```
...
final var model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
    model.addElement(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
}
...
ComboBox.setModel(model);
```

Comment: Capital C ComboBox was a weird choice for your variable name by the way. But I placed what I would have done into your syntax so you could see what I did there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I added DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>() intsead of final var model... I cannot use var because of netbeans realese 10. I got error NullPointerException.

Comment: Maybe someone else knows then. But I do always work with the model myself. After the JComboBox is built and in use, I just grab the model and use it like an array list, and it's always been more stable for me than the JComboBox methods. Good luck.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't work for me. I will look into it. Thank you very much for your help!